# php session hijacking - is HTTPS enough? Suggestions for fingerprinting?

Tags: php, security, apache, https, fingerprinting

I use HTTPS, but want to minimize the risk of someone evil crafting their own cookies with a session ID that someone else actually uses recently.

As a session variable I have an expiry time so the session is invalidated if it hasn't been used recently, so I figure the window of opportunity is when the victim is active or recently left the site without logging out properly.

I don't expect huge amounts of traffic and I use the standard php methods of generating session IDs. I believe the "risk" of someone actually succeed (or even try) hijacking someones session here is close to zero.

What I would want to do is to "identify" the remote user somehow, *without* using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. My thoughts being that the attacker would have to both find a valid session ID, *as well as* impersonating the different properties of the actual user.

I don't want to force the user to use a certificate to log in. I want it to work in all standard web browsers, even for my grandmother and other non tech-people like her.

So, what I originally wanted to ask was: are there any "properties" of the HTTPS session that could be used? Would they be useful? If so, how do I find them? `phpinfo()` reveals nothing HTTPS specific. (Is it because `httpd` doesn't expose it?)

Should I just use a concatenation of `HTTP_USER_AGENT` + `HTTP_ACCEPT` + `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` + `HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING` + `HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET` or something similar that is assumed to be *unique enough* between users?

Very happy for all answers! (But please read the question before answering with only referrals to other questions on StackOverflow)
Thank you!

Comment: Make sure you do all your research before you start coding yourself. Session security is a well known problem and if someone else has a well thought out and tested solution, I would consider using that first.

Comment: @Dana the Sane: and how do you know when the other's guy's code is better than yours?

Comment: @Dana the Sane: I agree. That's exactly why I'm asking here.

Comment: @symcbean Before writing any tricky code like this, you'd be well advised to review what the major php frameworks/libs are doing in this area. These packages aren't known for being the most secure, but they have accumulated bug fixes over time. If you can't identify  a session hijacking vulnerability in one of these, or can't figure out what all the code does, I think you're unlikely to come up with a better result.

Comment: Interesting point. If I write concise and correct code that does what I need and nothing more; does that make it less secure than a bloated framework with lots of unneeded features?  
If I can't figure out what the code in a framework/lib does, I will *definitely* not use it.  
By the way, there's nothing tricky about this kind of code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ensure that you've got both the secure and http_only flags set on your session cookies. You also need to change the session_id when a user authenticates to avoid session fixation problems.

While what you propose should be relatively safe in terms of finger-printing, it's not really all that selective - otoh there are lots things which should NOT be used for fingerprinting (like CLIENT_ADDRESS) so its not really very easy to suggest something better.

Apart from my suggestions above, I'd recommend spending your time looking at other potential security problems.

C.

Answer (score 2):

The [OWASP top 10](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-Main) is an excellent aid for this class of attacks.
Specificlly you need to worry about these three:

[A2: Cross-Site Scripting (XSS)](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A2-Cross-Site_Scripting_(XSS))

[A3: Broken Authentication and Session Management.](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Broken_Authentication_and_Session_Management)

[A5: Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF)](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A5-Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) (Also known as "Session Riding")

Almost all of the $_SESSION variables are known to the attacker and can be **any value**.  There is no point is checking these variables as it is trivial for an attacker influence them.  A important exception is `$_SERVER['remote_addr']` which is pulled directly from apache's TCP socket,  thus this value cannot be spoofed or otherwise tampered with.  However,  if the attacker is on the same network segment (such as if he was sipping a cup of coffee right behind you at the cafe),  then the attacker would have the same ip address.